# JavaScript loading problem

Tags: support

In my hotel in Shanghai, I get the error message

MathOverflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.

Is there a work around for this?  Posts load very slowly, I cannot vote, some comments are not viewable,...

Comment: Perhaps it's a slow internet connection? (I'm not sure, since I'm not a computer expert.)

Comment: Perhaps you're enjoying Chinese censorship? MathOverflow now works under https, so you might just try changing the URL to `https://mathoverflow.net/` and seeing what happens. Alternatively, presumably you have `ssh` access to some computer back home. Run `ssh -D 1080 username@math.tamu.edu`, and then tell your browser to use a SOCKS proxy on port 1080. (Google for more details, or just ask me.) This will tunnel you out of the Great Firewall.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, Scott.

Comment: I have yesterday seen this message as well, from Germany -- but the problem was intermittent -- sometimes I saw that message, sometimes the formulas were rendered strangely or not at all or omitted completely. But now everything seems to work well again.

Comment: Your problem was likely different, Stefan.  My problem was the Chinese firewall that had to be circumvented.

Comment: Scott's comment should probably be an answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is due to some *very aggressive* firewalls permitting our sites, but not our CDN (sstatic.net). You'll hit this, unfortunately quite often, in mainland China. If you're in the Special Administrative Regions (HK/Macau, etc) then you should be fine.

You have two options:

- Go with https:// (which sometimes works)
- Go with a proxy service like Hola Internet<sup>1</sup> or similar if that fails

It's hard to design around a use case of someone intentionally breaking the Internet, so unfortunately, there's not much we can do to get around it (if we want to use a CDN, which we really need to do). We're *hoping* that enough bug reports (yes, the GWOC does have a bug tracker so 'legitimate' domains can be unblocked) finally gets them to stop blocking our CDN.

<sup>1</sup><sub>We don't officially endorse any third party proxy, I've just had luck with them, as have users that acted on my recommendation to try them.</sub>

Comment: I tried https; it does not work.  I did not try Hola, but Scott Morrison's second suggestion allows me to work around the problem.  If Scott writes it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted?

Comment: @ToddTrimble [because I lost my keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/50049). Could be because it was answered in comments which I mostly reiterated, but .. it's my job to do that and make sure these have actual answers :)

Comment: @BillJohnson I think in some sense Scott Morrison's suggestion is a special case of the second point here, as it suggests to use a particular proxy.

Comment: @quid For me the key point in Scott's comment was to use the ssh -D 1080 command when connecting to my home domain via ssh.  I did not get that suggestion from my system administrator. I now set one browser to use that and a different browser to use the local port in Shanghai.

Comment: @BillJohnson Yes, a simple SOCKS proxy is the easiest way to go if you (1) have a decent SSH client that'll do it for you and (2) something you can connect to. I wrote a nice init script that wraps that all up simply with a nice launcher program, gotta dig that up and get it in my public repo.