# Using MO in China

Tags: support, bug

I am on a business trip in Beijing and get the following error message when using MO:
[image]

> **Question:** can that somehow be fixed?

Comment: I believe using any site from SE network might be problematic, although I do not know much about the details. Here are some posts related to the issue from other metas: [“Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain” message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89433), [Add a fallback for jQuery in case it fails to load from Google's CDN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133786) and [Use of ajax.googleapis.com not China friendly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258288).

Comment: Probably these two are closer to your problem: [MSE requires JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16661) and [JavaScript loading problem](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1746).

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks for the links; so the issue is already known, I will check the links for fixes.

Comment: To help nail down the issue, you can try and find out which script isn't loading by going to the dev tools (right click > inspect > debugger, tab sources, or inspect > console) and seeing which source is failing to load. If it's a script from `cdn.sstatic.net` it is most likely [this issue](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1746/javascript-loading-problem).

Comment: Using a SOCKS proxy might work.  Set it up with ssh -D 1080 user@host.com   The -D 1080 tells ssh to set up a SOCKS4 proxy on port 1080. Replace user@host.com with your actual username and remote host information, of course.  In a different terminal window, try open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --proxy-server="socks5://localhost:1080"  to force Chrome to use the SOCKS connection. Yours might be somewhat different. For me what works on my Mac is to replace Applications by users/[myname]

Comment: @BillJohnson: SOCKS proxies should be considered obsolete these days.  A much more convenient way to achieve the same aim is to use software like sshuttle (https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle), which completely transparently reroutes the entire Internet connection through an SSH server.

Comment: Has there anything been fixed already? Today everything seems to work fine. Thanks to all who have contributed to identify and/or fix the issue.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov:  Thanks for the tip.